# IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10 for rectangular array, but not square

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm using a `for` loop to iterate over an array and replace pixels as I go. So far, the code produces exactly the result I want, but only if the arrays are square. Ultimately, I'll need to do the same thing on rectangular arrays. If I change the dimensions in `line 7` to be, for example, `h, w = 10, 12`, I get an `IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10` error.

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  

#   Generate random image and mask
np.random.seed(seed=5)                      #   To use the same random numbers
h, w = 10,10

mask = np.random.randint(2, size=(h, w))    #   Generate a h x w array of 
                                            #   random integers from 0 - 1
img = np.random.rand(h, w)                  #   Generate a h x w array of 
                                            #   random floats
img_masked = np.where(mask, img, np.nan)    #   Mask the img array and replace
                                            #   invalid values with nan's

#   Use generic filter to compute nan-excluding median of masked image
size = 3
img_masked_median = ndi.generic_filter(img_masked, np.nanmedian, size=size)

new_img = np.ones_like(img_masked)
#   Use a for loop to look at each pixel in the masked, unfiltered image
height, width = img_masked.shape
for y in range(0, height):
    for x in range(0, width):
        if np.isnan(img_masked[x, y]):
            new_img[x, y] = img_masked_median[x, y]
        else:
            new_img[x, y] = img[x, y]
```

I know it's got something to do with looping across the length of the arrays, and I've read over the other questions that have the same error, but I can't find a solution for a square versus rectangular array.

I've also tried changing the loop to

```
for y in range(0, height + 1):
    for x in range(0, width + 1):
```

but I get the same error. Trying

```
for y in range(0, height - 1):
    for x in range(0, width - 1):
```

gives the wrong result.
How can I fix this so that it's within the bounds of the array?
And also, why does it happen only when w == h?

Comment: Which line is getting the error? My guess is that `img_masked_median` doesn't have the same size as `img_masked`.

Comment: I'm getting the in `line 25`. I'm using Spyder, and it's telling me that `img_masked` and `im_masked_median` are definitely the right size (10 x 12 if I change the dimensions as per the first paragraph).

Comment: Don't make me count lines, which line is getting the error?

Comment: Oh sorry!! It's

        if np.isnan(img_masked[x, y]):

Comment: I think you have your indexes backwards, it should be `[y, x]`.

Comment: 2-dimensional array indexes are `[row, column]`, and `y` ranges over the row numbers.

Comment: Oh!! i didn't even think to change those!!! Fixed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your array indexes backwards. 2-dimensional arrays are indexed as `[row, column]`. Since `y` loops over the row numbers, all your array indexes should be `[y, x]`, not `[x, y]`.